# React Developer Tools no aparece en DevTools

Tags: reactjs, extensión-google-chrome

Tengo instalado "React Developer Tools" en Chrome, pero no me aparece al entrar en DevTools. En la extensión tengo permitido la opción "Permitir acceso a la URL de archivo" pero aun así no funciona.